# Value transform.position changed before initialization [ARToolkit]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artoolkit

I have a simple script like below to change object position when the object is enabled :

```
void OnEnable() {
   isEnabled = true;
   Debug.Log(objectID + " " + isEnabled);
   Debug.Log("Pos1 : "+transform.position);
   transform.position = new Vector3(5, 5, 5);
   Debug.Log("Pos2 : " + transform.position);
}
```

But what's weird is in console it shows the value like this :
https://snag.gy/SLJWNC.jpg
Anyone can explain this ?

Comment: What's weird? What do you expect to show?

Comment: The Pos1 : value should be the position where it start

Comment: How about you select the object this script is attached to and post screenshot of it in the hierarchy and the position values in the Editor?

Comment: This is the screenshot in [editor](https://snag.gy/s1pGOI.jpg)

Comment: Where do you define the transform member value ? Maybe there is the error. Can you add the Code Snippet please.

Comment: @DomeTune The script derives from `MonoBehaviour` which declared `transform`.

Comment: @DomeTune Sure. I pasted the full code [here](http://pastebin.com/zS0PicLc) This code attached only to one game object I desired

Comment: @AliAkbar Did you read what's in my answer. Is it returning the right value?

Comment: @Programmer Yeah I tried your answer. But it still returning the wrong value.

Answer (score 0):

It is returning that position because it is a child GameObject. If you want the position it is showing in the Editor, you have to use `transform.localPosition`.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response. So I have tested with transform.localPosition and compared it with new and clean scene. With a same script attached this is the [result](https://snag.gy/LX9MJZ.jpg).

Comment: In case you wonder what my [DebugTools.cs](http://pastebin.com/7bLqhRRP) script looks like.

Comment: In this case, it is working properly. The [first](https://snag.gy/LX9MJZ.jpg) screenshot in the comment shows that it is now working properly. The default position for the GameObject is 0,0,0. You showed the default value with `Debug.Log("Pos1 : " + transform.localPosition);` then you modified it with `transform.localPosition = new Vector3(3, 3, 3);` which makes it to be 3,3,3. Then showed the position again. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: No sir, it returns the wrong value. This [picture](https://snag.gy/LX9MJZ.jpg) have 2 screenshot scenes. I'm afraid that you didn't notice that I put 2 screenshots in 1 picture.

Comment: First screenshot returns right value while the second one returns wrong value.

Comment: Clear the console then show me the **first** printed message for the second image. The stuff you showed me is not the first printed message. Also, it is likely that you attached the script to another GameObject too and that text you see if from another GameObject. Please add `Debug.Log("Name: " + gameObject.name);` under both Debug.Log then update the log you see on screen.

Comment: That's because the marker sometimes lost thus it makes the child object disabled and sometimes got marker that will make the child object enabled then OnEnabled get called. But it's okay I will show you the [first printed message](https://snag.gy/YpMogh.jpg).

Comment: You are changing it to 3,3,3 and it's printing 3,3,3. What's wrong again? It is also 3,3,3 in the Editor

Comment: I didn't change the value before the first Debug.Log sir. I changed the value after the first Debug.Log. You can see that in [this](http://pastebin.com/7bLqhRRP) code I didn't make any change to the transform.localPosition before the first Debug.Log.

Comment: It's so hard to understand what's going on. Another script is likely moving it. You can attach the project if you want further help otherwise I have no idea what's going on at this point.

Comment: Ok so where can I send you my project in private ?

Comment: Send it to my email "programmercert+gmail.com". Replace the `+` with `@`

Comment: Hi, I've sent it to your email. Please check it out.